# python smtp check if username and pass are correct

Tags: python, smtp

Do you have any idea how would i check if username and password are typed correctly before sending smtp mail with python?

meaning: connect to smpt server, give feedback on username and password

Comment: You can't do like this. You can just check if a username and a password matches together, or if a given username exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could using a try and except inside a while loop

```
#Inital user and passw need to be defined up here
log=False
while log==False: #to loop until a correct password is aqquired
    try:
        server.login(user, passw) #attempt to log into smtp server
        log=True #sets to true if log in is successful
    except:
        print('Incorrect Username or Password:\n')
        user=input('Enter new Username: ') #gets new username and password
        passw=input('Enter new Password: ')
```

This should just loop through until a correct username or password is entered,
then it will log in